# Python is it possible to put two if and one else statements together?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
if 'a' in dict:
    dict['a'] do something
if 'b' in dict:
    dict['b'] do something
# After checking the above two if statements, run the else statement below
else:
    dict do something
```

I'd like to check if `'a'` or `'b'` in `dict`. If I use `elif` statement, then checking `'b'` would be skipped if `'a'` is in `dict`.

Is it possible to check the above 2 cases, if both `'a'` and `'b'` not in `dict`, then we `else` to do something else?

I can implement it in a tedious way though.

```
if `'a' or 'b'` in dict:
    if 'a' in dict:
        dict['a'] do something
    if 'b' in dict:
        dict['b'] do something
else:
    dict do something
```

Comment: *..If I use elif statement, then checking 'b' would be skipped if 'a' is in dict...* with that sentence it becomes unclear what functionality you actually want.

Comment: You have written "do something" many times.  Please clarify if these somethings are supposed to be the same something, or different somethings (i.e., do you want to do *different* things when a is in the dict than when b is in the dict).

Comment: "Is it possible to check the above 2 cases, if both 'a' and 'b' not in dict, then we else to do something else?" ok so why dont you do it ? like `if a not in dict and b not in dict do something else dosomething` I don't really understand where is the problem

Comment: Looks like there is quite a bit of contention and confusion down below about how to answer this question, consider being more specific about what you are trying to do. For example if you were to write this out in pure logic rather than Python what would that look like?

Comment: BTW, @user8314628  `'a' or 'b' in dict` will most likely bite you in the ass sooner or later. It does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dictionary = {"a":1, "b":2}
if (cond1 := "a" in dictionary) | (cond2 := "b" in dictionary):
    if cond1:
        pass
    if cond2:
        pass
else:
    pass
```

Using somewhat recent addition to the language - `:=` operator you can capture the value of both conditions. While you still need to check if they are true or false separately, it lets you skip repeating the same check twice.

`|` has to be used instead of `or` due to lazy evaluation of the latter - if cond1 is True, 2nd condition will never be checked and cond2 will be undefined. `|` will make sure both conditions are checked, but it makes the solution not as pretty as it should be.

Comment: While this is a good use of the walrus operator this is practically the same as the OP's "tedious solution" (but i suppose that depends on what they mean by tedious...)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea - first check if none of the relevant keys are present; if that's `False`, then execute the relevant action for each relevant key that is indeed present.

This can be simplified if you have another dictionary where you keep the relationship of each `key: action` associated (this means that your `do something`s should become proper functions).

Something like:

```
# Put your logic for each key here
def do_something_no_keys(): 
    print('No keys found!')

def do_something_a(): 
    print('Key "a" found!')

def do_something_b(): 
    print('Key "b" found!')

# Associate each possible key with their logic here
action_dict = {
    'a': do_something_a,
    'b': do_something_b,
}

# These are the values that you want to check
value_dict = {
    'a': 'foo',
    'c': 'bar',
}

if all(key not in value_dict for key in action_dict):
    do_something_no_keys()
else:
    for key, action in action_dict.items():
        if key in value_dict:
            action()
```

Current output is `Key "a" found!`, but you can see this change if you modify the keys in the `value_dict`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to have the `if`s only check one of a or b, but then somehow have the `else` take account of both a and b at once.  If you want to have one code branch for a alone, one for b alone, and one for the combination (or its negation), you need three ifs somehow or other.  Your "tedious" example with nested ifs is a perfectly reasonable solution.

It's hard to tell from the question exactly what you would consider a satisfying alternative, but here's one:

```
if 'a' in d:
    do_something(d['a'])
if 'b' in d:
    do_something(d['b'])
if 'a' not in d and 'b' not in d:
    do_something_else()
```

This avoids the extra level of nesting by making a third if that just checks for the negation of the disjunction of the earlier two conditions.  This isn't really any better than your "tedious" solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing checks, using ideas from other answers:

```
if first := "a" in dictionary:
    print("a")
if "b" in dictionary:
    print("b")
elif not first:
    print("Neither")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
neither_a_nor_b = True

if 'a' in dict:
    neither_a_nor_b = False
    # suite 1

if 'b' in dict:
    neither_a_nor_b = False
    # suite 2

if neither_a_nor_b:
    # suite 3
```

If suites 1 and 2 are the same, you can use a loop:

```
neither_a_nor_b = True

for x in ['a', 'b']:
    if x in dict:
        neither_a_nor_b = False
        # suite 1/2

if neither_a_nor_b:
    # suite 3
```

Though in either case, you  might simply replace `neither_a_nor_b` with an explicit (if redundant) test like `all(x not in dict for x in ['a', 'b'])`.

Comment: I'd prefer the `a_or_b` version.

Answer (score 0):

You can stack if statements and use an elif statement:

```
dictionary = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
    if "a" in dictionary:
        print("a")
    if "b" in dictionary:
        print("b")
    elif "a" not in dictionary and "b" not in dictionary:
        print("Neither")
```

Prints:

```
a
b
```

While

```
dictionary = {"z": 1, "x": 2}
    if "a" in dictionary:
        print("a")
    if "b" in dictionary:
        print("b")
    elif "a" not in dictionary and "b" not in dictionary:
        print("Neither")
```

Prints:

```
Neither
```

Comment: If you remove the `and "b" not in dictionary`, you have something interesting.